# Выпадающим список с js, при выборе слетает верстка

Tags: jquery, битрикс

[Есть сайт](https://mobideek.ru/catalog/zashchita_ekrana_1/filter/brend_mobidik-is-ce1f974b-a64e-11ea-80e1-002127fc1de9/znachenie_brenda_mobidik-is-3e2d822e-a97a-11ea-80e3-002127fc1de9/apply/)

Есть проблема, если выбирать среди производителей или моделей, список начинает слетать в left:0 top:0 от всего экрана, раньше такой проблемы небыло, не подскажите в чем проблема?
Пытался разными способами,

```
JCSmartFilter.prototype.selectDropDownItem = function(elem, controlId) {
  // this.keyup(BX(controlId)); //undefined
  console.log('this: ' + this.value);
  console.log('controlId: ' + BX(controlId).value);
  console.log('Это selectDropDown: ' + this.keyup(BX(controlId)));
  // var wrapContainer = BX.findParent(BX(controlId), {className:"bx_filter_select_container"}, false);

  // var currentOption = wrapContainer.querySelector('[data-role="currentOption"]');
  // currentOption.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;
  // BX.PopupWindowManager.getCurrentPopup().close();
  console.log("работает");
};
```

Видимо при перезагрузке страницы(а вроде ajax) теряет значения и this переходит вообще к body

сам скрипт

```
function JCSmartFilter(ajaxURL, params) {
    this.ajaxURL = ajaxURL;
    this.form = null;
    this.timer = null;
    if(params && params.SEF_SET_FILTER_URL) {
        this.bindUrlToButton('set_filter', params.SEF_SET_FILTER_URL);
        this.sef = true;
    }
    if(params && params.SEF_DEL_FILTER_URL) {
        this.bindUrlToButton('del_filter', params.SEF_DEL_FILTER_URL);
    }   
}

JCSmartFilter.prototype.keyup = function(input) {
    // if(!!this.timer) {
    //  console.log('this.time, after bool:');
    //  console.log(this.timer);
    //  clearTimeout(this.timer);
    // }
    // this.timer = setTimeout(BX.delegate(function(){
    //  this.reload(input);
    // }, this), 500);
    // console.log('this.timer:');
    // console.log(this.timer);
    var thisUrl = document.createElement('a');
    console.log('keyup this:')
    console.log(this.ajaxURL);
    console.log('------')
    setTimeout(BX.delegate(function(){
        this.reload(input);
    }, this), 500);
};

JCSmartFilter.prototype.click = function(checkbox, INSTANT_RELOAD) {    
    if(!!this.timer) {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
    
    if(!!INSTANT_RELOAD) {
        var customForm = BX.findParent(checkbox);
        BX.toggleClass(BX(customForm),"active");
    }
    
    this.timer = setTimeout(BX.delegate(function(){
        this.reload(checkbox);
    }, this), 500); 
};

JCSmartFilter.prototype.reload = function(input) {
    var values = [];

    this.position = BX.pos(input, true);
    this.form = BX.findParent(input, {'tag':'form'});
    if(this.form) {
        values[0] = {name: 'ajax', value: 'y'};
        this.gatherInputsValues(values, BX.findChildren(this.form, {'tag': new RegExp('^(input|select)$', 'i')}, true));
        
        this.curFilterinput = input;
        BX.ajax.loadJSON(
            this.ajaxURL,
            this.values2post(values),
            BX.delegate(this.postHandler, this)
        );
    }
};

JCSmartFilter.prototype.updateItem = function (PID, arItem) {
    if(arItem.PROPERTY_TYPE === 'N' || arItem.PRICE) {
        var trackBar = window['trackBar' + PID];
        if(!trackBar && arItem.ENCODED_ID)
            trackBar = window['trackBar' + arItem.ENCODED_ID];

        if(trackBar && arItem.VALUES) {
            if(arItem.VALUES.MIN) {
                if(arItem.VALUES.MIN.FILTERED_VALUE)
                    trackBar.setMinFilteredValue(arItem.VALUES.MIN.FILTERED_VALUE);
                else
                    trackBar.setMinFilteredValue(arItem.VALUES.MIN.VALUE);
            }

            if(arItem.VALUES.MAX) {
                if(arItem.VALUES.MAX.FILTERED_VALUE)
                    trackBar.setMaxFilteredValue(arItem.VALUES.MAX.FILTERED_VALUE);
                else
                    trackBar.setMaxFilteredValue(arItem.VALUES.MAX.VALUE);
            }
        }
    } else if(arItem.VALUES) {
        for(var i in arItem.VALUES) {
            if(arItem.VALUES.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                var value = arItem.VALUES[i];
                var control = BX(value.CONTROL_ID);

                if(!!control) {
                    var label = document.querySelector('[data-role="label_'+value.CONTROL_ID+'"]');
                    if(value.DISABLED) {                        
                        BX.adjust(control, {props: {disabled: true}});
                        if(label)
                            BX.addClass(label, 'disabled');
                        else
                            BX.addClass(control.parentNode, 'disabled');                        
                    } else {
                        BX.adjust(control, {props: {disabled: false}});
                        if(label)
                            BX.removeClass(label, 'disabled');
                        else
                            BX.removeClass(control.parentNode, 'disabled');
                    }
                    if(value.hasOwnProperty('ELEMENT_COUNT')) {
                        label = document.querySelector('[data-role="count_'+value.CONTROL_ID+'"]');
                        if(label)
                            label.innerHTML = value.ELEMENT_COUNT;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

JCSmartFilter.prototype.postHandler = function (result) {
    var hrefFILTER, url, curProp;
    var modef = BX('modef');
    var modef_popup = BX('modef_popup');
    var modef_num = BX('modef_num');
    var modef_popup_num = BX('modef_popup_num');

    if(!!result && !!result.ITEMS) {
        for(var PID in result.ITEMS) {
            if(result.ITEMS.hasOwnProperty(PID)) {
                this.updateItem(PID, result.ITEMS[PID]);
            }
        }               

        if(!!modef && !!modef_num) {
            modef_num.innerHTML = result.ELEMENT_COUNT;
            if(modef.style.display === 'none') {
                modef.style.display = 'inline-block';
            }
        }
        
        if(!!modef_popup && !!modef_popup_num) {
            modef_popup_num.innerHTML = result.ELEMENT_COUNT;
            hrefFILTER = BX.findChildren(modef_popup, {tag: 'A'}, true);

            if(result.FILTER_URL && hrefFILTER) {
                hrefFILTER[0].href = BX.util.htmlspecialcharsback(result.FILTER_URL);
            }

            if(result.FILTER_AJAX_URL && result.COMPONENT_CONTAINER_ID) {
                BX.bind(hrefFILTER[0], 'click', function(e) {
                    var url = BX.util.htmlspecialcharsback(result.FILTER_AJAX_URL);
                    BX.ajax.insertToNode(url, result.COMPONENT_CONTAINER_ID);
                    return BX.PreventDefault(e);
                });
            }

            if(result.INSTANT_RELOAD && result.COMPONENT_CONTAINER_ID) {
                url = BX.util.htmlspecialcharsback(result.FILTER_AJAX_URL);
                BX.ajax.insertToNode(url, result.COMPONENT_CONTAINER_ID);
            } else {
                if(modef_popup.style.display === 'none') {
                    modef_popup.style.display = 'inline-block';
                }
                curProp = BX.findChild(BX.findParent(this.curFilterinput, {'class':'bx_filter_box'}), {'class':'bx_filter_container_modef_popup'}, true, false);
                curProp.appendChild(modef_popup);               
                if(result.SEF_SET_FILTER_URL) {
                    this.bindUrlToButton('set_filter', result.SEF_SET_FILTER_URL);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

JCSmartFilter.prototype.bindUrlToButton = function (buttonId, url) {
    var button = BX(buttonId);
    if(button) {
        var proxy = function(j, func) {
            return function() {
                return func(j);
            }
        };

        if(button.type == 'submit')
            button.type = 'button';

        BX.bind(button, 'click', proxy(url, function(url) {
            window.location.href = url;
            return false;
        }));
    }
};

JCSmartFilter.prototype.gatherInputsValues = function (values, elements) {
    if(elements) {
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var el = elements[i];
            if(el.disabled || !el.type)
                continue;

            switch(el.type.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'text':
                case 'textarea':
                case 'password':
                case 'hidden':
                case 'select-one':
                    if(el.value.length)
                        values[values.length] = {name : el.name, value : el.value};
                    break;
                case 'radio':
                case 'checkbox':
                    if(el.checked)
                        values[values.length] = {name : el.name, value : el.value};
                    break;
                case 'select-multiple':
                    for(var j = 0; j < el.options.length; j++) {
                        if (el.options[j].selected)
                            values[values.length] = {name : el.name, value : el.options[j].value};
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

JCSmartFilter.prototype.values2post = function (values) {
    var post = new Array;
    var current = post;
    var i = 0;
    while(i < values.length) {
        var p = values[i].name.indexOf('[');
        if(p == -1) {
            current[values[i].name] = values[i].value;
            current = post;
            i++;
        } else {
            var name = values[i].name.substring(0, p);
            var rest = values[i].name.substring(p+1);
            if(!current[name])
                current[name] = new Array;

            var pp = rest.indexOf(']');
            if(pp == -1) {
                //Error - not balanced brackets
                current = post;
                i++;
            } else if(pp == 0) {
                //No index specified - so take the next integer
                current = current[name];
                values[i].name = '' + current.length;
            } else {
                //Now index name becomes and name and we go deeper into the array
                current = current[name];
                values[i].name = rest.substring(0, pp) + rest.substring(pp+1);
            }
        }
    }
    return post;
};

JCSmartFilter.prototype.hideFilterProps = function(element) {
    var easing,
        obj = element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode,
        filterBlock = BX.findChild(obj, {className:"bx_filter_block"}, true, false),
        faWrap = BX.findChild(obj, {className:"sect__arrow"}, true, false),
        fa = BX.findChildren(faWrap, {className: "fa"}, true);
    
    if(BX.hasClass(obj, "active")) {
        easing = new BX.easing({
            duration : 300,
            start : { opacity: 1 },
            finish : { opacity: 0 },
            transition : BX.easing.transitions.quart,
            step : function(state){
                filterBlock.style.opacity = state.opacity;
            },
            complete : function() {
                filterBlock.setAttribute("style", "");
                BX.removeClass(obj, "active");
                if(!!fa && 0 < fa.length) {
                    for(i = 0; i < fa.length; i++) {
                        if(BX.hasClass(fa[i], "fa-angle-left"))
                            BX.toggleClass(fa[i], ["fa-angle-left", "fa-angle-right"]);
                        else if(BX.hasClass(fa[i], "fa-angle-up"))
                            BX.toggleClass(fa[i], ["fa-angle-up", "fa-angle-down"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        easing.animate();
    } else {
        filterBlock.style.opacity = 0;
        
        easing = new BX.easing({
            duration : 300,
            start : { opacity: 0 },
            finish : { opacity: 1 },
            transition : BX.easing.transitions.quart,
            step : function(state){
                filterBlock.style.opacity = state.opacity;
            },
            complete : function() {}
        });
        easing.animate();
        BX.addClass(obj, "active");
        if(!!fa && 0 < fa.length) {
            for(i = 0; i < fa.length; i++) {
                if(BX.hasClass(fa[i], "fa-angle-right"))
                    BX.toggleClass(fa[i], ["fa-angle-left", "fa-angle-right"]);
                else if(BX.hasClass(fa[i], "fa-angle-down"))
                    BX.toggleClass(fa[i], ["fa-angle-up", "fa-angle-down"]);
            }
        }
    }
};

JCSmartFilter.prototype.showDropDownPopup = function(element, popupId) {
    var contentNode = element.querySelector('[data-role="dropdownContent"]');
    console.log('showDropDownPopup this element: ');
    console.log(element);
    BX.PopupWindowManager.create("smartFilterDropDown"+popupId, element, {
        bindElement: element,
        autoHide: true,
        offsetLeft: 0,
        offsetTop: 3,
        overlay: false,
        draggable: {restrict:true},
        closeByEsc: true,
        content: contentNode
    }).show();
};

var showDropDownPopup1 = smartFilter.showDropDownPopup.bind(element);

JCSmartFilter.prototype.showAlert = function() {
    alert('Warning!');
}

JCSmartFilter.prototype.selectDropDownItem = function(elem, controlId) {
    // this.keyup(BX(controlId)); //undefined
    console.log('1) elem:');
    console.log(elem);
    console.log('2) this:');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
    console.log('3) controlId:');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(controlId));
    console.log('4) BX(controlId)');
    console.log(BX(controlId));
    console.log('5) this.keyup(BX(controlID))'); 

    console.log('--' + this.keyup(BX(controlId))); //теряется this
    // var wrapContainer = BX.findParent(BX(controlId), {className:"bx_filter_select_container"}, false);

    // var currentOption = wrapContainer.querySelector('[data-role="currentOption"]');
    // currentOption.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;
    // BX.PopupWindowManager.getCurrentPopup().close();
};

BX.namespace("BX.Iblock.SmartFilter");
BX.Iblock.SmartFilter = (function() {
    var SmartFilter = function(arParams) {
        if(typeof arParams === 'object') {
            this.leftSlider = BX(arParams.leftSlider);
            this.rightSlider = BX(arParams.rightSlider);
            this.tracker = BX(arParams.tracker);
            this.trackerWrap = BX(arParams.trackerWrap);

            this.minInput = BX(arParams.minInputId);
            this.maxInput = BX(arParams.maxInputId);

            this.minPrice = parseFloat(arParams.minPrice);
            this.maxPrice = parseFloat(arParams.maxPrice);

            this.curMinPrice = parseFloat(arParams.curMinPrice);
            this.curMaxPrice = parseFloat(arParams.curMaxPrice);

            this.fltMinPrice = arParams.fltMinPrice ? parseFloat(arParams.fltMinPrice) : parseFloat(arParams.curMinPrice);
            this.fltMaxPrice = arParams.fltMaxPrice ? parseFloat(arParams.fltMaxPrice) : parseFloat(arParams.curMaxPrice);

            this.precision = arParams.precision || 0;

            this.priceDiff = this.maxPrice - this.minPrice;

            this.leftPercent = 0;
            this.rightPercent = 0;

            this.fltMinPercent = 0;
            this.fltMaxPercent = 0;

            this.colorUnavailableActive = BX(arParams.colorUnavailableActive);//gray
            this.colorAvailableActive = BX(arParams.colorAvailableActive);//blue
            this.colorAvailableInactive = BX(arParams.colorAvailableInactive);//light blue

            this.isTouch = false;

            this.init();

            if('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
                this.isTouch = true;

                BX.bind(this.leftSlider, "touchstart", BX.proxy(function(event){
                    this.onMoveLeftSlider(event)
                }, this));

                BX.bind(this.rightSlider, "touchstart", BX.proxy(function(event){
                    this.onMoveRightSlider(event)
                }, this));
            } else {
                BX.bind(this.leftSlider, "mousedown", BX.proxy(function(event){
                    this.onMoveLeftSlider(event)
                }, this));

                BX.bind(this.rightSlider, "mousedown", BX.proxy(function(event){
                    this.onMoveRightSlider(event)
                }, this));
            }

            BX.bind(this.minInput, "keyup", BX.proxy(function(event){
                this.onInputChange();
            }, this));

            BX.bind(this.maxInput, "keyup", BX.proxy(function(event){
                this.onInputChange();
            }, this));
        }
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.init = function() {
        var priceDiff;

        if(this.curMinPrice > this.minPrice) {
            priceDiff = this.curMinPrice - this.minPrice;
            this.leftPercent = (priceDiff*100)/this.priceDiff;

            this.leftSlider.style.left = this.leftPercent + "%";
            this.colorUnavailableActive.style.left = this.leftPercent + "%";
        }

        this.setMinFilteredValue(this.fltMinPrice);

        if(this.curMaxPrice < this.maxPrice) {
            priceDiff = this.maxPrice - this.curMaxPrice;
            this.rightPercent = (priceDiff*100)/this.priceDiff;

            this.rightSlider.style.right = this.rightPercent + "%";
            this.colorUnavailableActive.style.right = this.rightPercent + "%";
        }

        this.setMaxFilteredValue(this.fltMaxPrice);
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.setMinFilteredValue = function (fltMinPrice) {
        this.fltMinPrice = parseFloat(fltMinPrice);
        if(this.fltMinPrice >= this.minPrice) {
            var priceDiff = this.fltMinPrice - this.minPrice;
            this.fltMinPercent = (priceDiff*100)/this.priceDiff;

            if(this.leftPercent > this.fltMinPercent)
                this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = this.leftPercent + "%";
            else
                this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = this.fltMinPercent + "%";

            this.colorAvailableInactive.style.left = this.fltMinPercent + "%";
        } else {
            this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = "0%";
            this.colorAvailableInactive.style.left = "0%";
        }
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.setMaxFilteredValue = function (fltMaxPrice) {
        this.fltMaxPrice = parseFloat(fltMaxPrice);
        if(this.fltMaxPrice <= this.maxPrice) {
            var priceDiff = this.maxPrice - this.fltMaxPrice;
            this.fltMaxPercent = (priceDiff*100)/this.priceDiff;

            if(this.rightPercent > this.fltMaxPercent)
                this.colorAvailableActive.style.right = this.rightPercent + "%";
            else
                this.colorAvailableActive.style.right = this.fltMaxPercent + "%";

            this.colorAvailableInactive.style.right = this.fltMaxPercent + "%";
        } else {
            this.colorAvailableActive.style.right = "0%";
            this.colorAvailableInactive.style.right = "0%";
        }
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.getXCoord = function(elem) {
        var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        var body = document.body;
        var docElem = document.documentElement;

        var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;
        var clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;
        var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;
        
        return Math.round(left);
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.getPageX = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var pageX = null;

        if(this.isTouch && event.targetTouches[0] != null) {
            pageX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX;
        } else if (e.pageX != null) {
            pageX = e.pageX;
        } else if (e.clientX != null) {
            var html = document.documentElement;
            var body = document.body;

            pageX = e.clientX + (html.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0);
            pageX -= html.clientLeft || 0;
        }

        return pageX;
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.recountMinPrice = function() {
        var newMinPrice = (this.priceDiff*this.leftPercent)/100;
        newMinPrice = (this.minPrice + newMinPrice).toFixed(this.precision);

        if(newMinPrice != this.minPrice)
            this.minInput.value = newMinPrice;
        else
            this.minInput.value = "";
        smartFilter.keyup(this.minInput);
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.recountMaxPrice = function() {
        var newMaxPrice = (this.priceDiff*this.rightPercent)/100;
        newMaxPrice = (this.maxPrice - newMaxPrice).toFixed(this.precision);

        if(newMaxPrice != this.maxPrice)
            this.maxInput.value = newMaxPrice;
        else
            this.maxInput.value = "";
        smartFilter.keyup(this.maxInput);
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.onInputChange = function () {
        var posMin = this.minInput.value.indexOf(",");
        if(posMin !== -1){
            this.minInput.value = this.minInput.value.replace(",",".");
            this.minInput.setSelectionRange(posMin+1,posMin+1);
        }
        
        var posMax = this.maxInput.value.indexOf(",");
        if(posMax !== -1){
            this.maxInput.value = this.maxInput.value.replace(",",".");
            this.maxInput.setSelectionRange(posMax+1,posMax+1);
        }
        var priceDiff;
        if(this.minInput.value) {
            var leftInputValue = this.minInput.value;
            if (leftInputValue < this.minPrice)
                leftInputValue = this.minPrice;

            if (leftInputValue > this.maxPrice)
                leftInputValue = this.maxPrice;

            priceDiff = leftInputValue - this.minPrice;
            this.leftPercent = (priceDiff*100)/this.priceDiff;

            this.makeLeftSliderMove(false);
        }

        if(this.maxInput.value) {
            var rightInputValue = this.maxInput.value;
            if (rightInputValue < this.minPrice)
                rightInputValue = this.minPrice;

            if (rightInputValue > this.maxPrice)
                rightInputValue = this.maxPrice;

            priceDiff = this.maxPrice - rightInputValue;
            this.rightPercent = (priceDiff*100)/this.priceDiff;

            this.makeRightSliderMove(false);
        }
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.makeLeftSliderMove = function(recountPrice) {
        recountPrice = (recountPrice === false) ? false : true;

        this.leftSlider.style.left = this.leftPercent + "%";
        this.colorUnavailableActive.style.left = this.leftPercent + "%";

        var areBothSlidersMoving = false;
        if(this.leftPercent + this.rightPercent >= 100) {
            areBothSlidersMoving = true;
            this.rightPercent = 100 - this.leftPercent;
            this.rightSlider.style.right = this.rightPercent + "%";
            this.colorUnavailableActive.style.right = this.rightPercent + "%";
        }

        if(this.leftPercent >= this.fltMinPercent && this.leftPercent <= (100-this.fltMaxPercent)) {
            this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = this.leftPercent + "%";
            if(areBothSlidersMoving) {
                this.colorAvailableActive.style.right = 100 - this.leftPercent + "%";
            }
        } else if(this.leftPercent <= this.fltMinPercent) {
            this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = this.fltMinPercent + "%";
            if(areBothSlidersMoving) {
                this.colorAvailableActive.style.right = 100 - this.fltMinPercent + "%";
            }
        } else if(this.leftPercent >= this.fltMaxPercent) {
            this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = 100-this.fltMaxPercent + "%";
            if(areBothSlidersMoving) {
                this.colorAvailableActive.style.right = this.fltMaxPercent + "%";
            }
        }

        if(recountPrice) {
            this.recountMinPrice();
            if(areBothSlidersMoving)
                this.recountMaxPrice();
        }
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.countNewLeft = function(event) {
        pageX = this.getPageX(event);

        var trackerXCoord = this.getXCoord(this.trackerWrap);
        var rightEdge = this.trackerWrap.offsetWidth;

        var newLeft = pageX - trackerXCoord;

        if (newLeft < 0)
            newLeft = 0;
        else if (newLeft > rightEdge)
            newLeft = rightEdge;

        return newLeft;
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.onMoveLeftSlider = function(e) {
        if(!this.isTouch) {
            this.leftSlider.ondragstart = function() {
                return false;
            };
        }

        if(!this.isTouch) {
            document.onmousemove = BX.proxy(function(event) {
                this.leftPercent = ((this.countNewLeft(event)*100)/this.trackerWrap.offsetWidth);
                this.makeLeftSliderMove();
            }, this);

            document.onmouseup = function() {
                document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
            };
        } else {
            document.ontouchmove = BX.proxy(function(event) {
                this.leftPercent = ((this.countNewLeft(event)*100)/this.trackerWrap.offsetWidth);
                this.makeLeftSliderMove();
            }, this);

            document.ontouchend = function() {
                document.ontouchmove = document.touchend = null;
            };
        }

        return false;
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.makeRightSliderMove = function(recountPrice) {
        recountPrice = (recountPrice === false) ? false : true;

        this.rightSlider.style.right = this.rightPercent + "%";
        this.colorUnavailableActive.style.right = this.rightPercent + "%";

        var areBothSlidersMoving = false;
        if(this.leftPercent + this.rightPercent >= 100) {
            areBothSlidersMoving = true;
            this.leftPercent = 100 - this.rightPercent;
            this.leftSlider.style.left = this.leftPercent + "%";
            this.colorUnavailableActive.style.left = this.leftPercent + "%";
        }

        if((100-this.rightPercent) >= this.fltMinPercent && this.rightPercent >= this.fltMaxPercent) {
            this.colorAvailableActive.style.right = this.rightPercent + "%";
            if(areBothSlidersMoving) {
                this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = 100 - this.rightPercent + "%";
            }
        } else if(this.rightPercent <= this.fltMaxPercent) {
            this.colorAvailableActive.style.right = this.fltMaxPercent + "%";
            if(areBothSlidersMoving) {
                this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = 100 - this.fltMaxPercent + "%";
            }
        } else if((100-this.rightPercent) <= this.fltMinPercent) {
            this.colorAvailableActive.style.right = 100-this.fltMinPercent + "%";
            if(areBothSlidersMoving) {
                this.colorAvailableActive.style.left = this.fltMinPercent + "%";
            }
        }

        if(recountPrice) {
            this.recountMaxPrice();
            if(areBothSlidersMoving)
                this.recountMinPrice();
        }
    };

    SmartFilter.prototype.onMoveRightSlider = function(e) {
        if(!this.isTouch) {
            this.rightSlider.ondragstart = function() {
                return false;
            };
        }

        if(!this.isTouch) {
            document.onmousemove = BX.proxy(function(event) {
                this.rightPercent = 100-(((this.countNewLeft(event))*100)/(this.trackerWrap.offsetWidth));
                this.makeRightSliderMove();
            }, this);

            document.onmouseup = function() {
                document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
            };
        } else {
            document.ontouchmove = BX.proxy(function(event) {
                this.rightPercent = 100-(((this.countNewLeft(event))*100)/(this.trackerWrap.offsetWidth));
                this.makeRightSliderMove();
            }, this);

            document.ontouchend = function() {
                document.ontouchmove = document.ontouchend = null;
            };
        }

        return false;
    };

    return SmartFilter;
})();
```

Comment: `smartFilter.showDropDownPopup(this, '5382')` что внутри?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц добавил код